Error en el for BatchScript
@echo off
set local enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion
set "repertorioA=M:\RepertorioA"
...
...
:lecturaArchivo 
for %%F in ("%repertorioA%\*") do (
set "nomFich=%%~nF"
set "ruta=%%~nF"
echo Nombre fichero : !nomFich!
echo ruta general : !ruta!
.... 
....
....
....)
goto lecturaArchivo
....

La ejecución llega al for y salta a la instrucción siguiente fuera del bucle (goto lecturaArchivo)
Este bloque es parte de un gran programa, en el pasado ha funcionado pero ahora no, ha habido probablemente un cambio a nivel del sistema que habría afectado el for, ¿podrían decirme por favor cómo corregirlo?

Parece que estas ejecutando un bucle
pon un pause>nul para que te deje ver el resultado
o usa las variables con el resultado fuera del for

En primer lugar algunas erratas, creo:

Debería ser "setlocal" en lugar de "set local"
La "ruta" debería obtenerse como %%~pF y no como %%~nF que es para "NomFich"

Por lo que dices deduzco que en ningún momento se producen las salidas de los ECHOs que figuran dentro del bucle FOR. Parece como si en %repertorioA%* no hubiera archivos. Puedes probar a poner un comando DIR "%repertorioA%*" antes del FOR para comprobarlo
